# How to store nested objects in Apache solr from spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr

I have class called employee and it contains address object,

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SolrDocument(collection ="Employee" )
public class Employee {

@Indexed
private String name;
@Indexed
@Id
private String id;
@Indexed
private List<Address> address;
}


@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Address {

private String addressLine;
private String zipcode;
private String State;
private String country;
}
```

when I try to get the employee details from Apache solr, it giving the address object data with full qualified name(along with package and class name) as shown below. Let me know how to get only address out of it.

```
{
"name": "employee1",
"id": "1",
"address": [
    "com.apachesolr.sample.application.model.Address:Address(addressLine=xyz street, zipcode=12345, State=AP, country=India)"
]
```

}

I tried indexing the data from spring boot application using solrCrudRepository it indexed fine.but when I try to retrieve it. It giving the documents along with qualified name of the document. I have used managed schema that will be created automatically when creating the core.

Comment: Please share more details e.g., schema design, code snippet etc.

Comment: question edited with asked details, please check and let me know if you need more details